# How to read form data in the AWS Lambda written in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I'm building an app using ReactJS in the front-end and back-end as AWS API Gateway/AWS Lambda written in NodeJS.
I'm passing the form data of my React app in the attribute called **userAttributes** like below:

[image]

I want to read this data in the backend logic. As per the Cloud Watch logs of Lambda, I'm getting the form data in the Lambda event as:-

```
  body: '------WebKitFormBoundarytTytoOIkcO2\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userAttributes"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '[object Object]\r\n' +
    '------WebKitFormBoundarytTytrEkb0oOIkcO2--\r\n',
  isBase64Encoded: false
}
```

Here [object Object] is my Form data. How can parse and read this form data value? I can read my other query string parameters (event.queryStringParameters.<attributes>) but not sure how to read the form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart on your lambda and you can parse the data...

But first

- Set the media type in you api gateway as multipart/form-data
- When you added your lambda to the api gateway method please be sure
  if you check "proxy" because you need that to manage the data from the frontend as multipar/form-data

Comment: thanks, API gateway is set to 'proxy' only. Thanks for the reference link.